# Sending username and password with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to access an API using php cURL. The docs say:

> Each request must include the API Key that was assigned to the email
>   partner. It should be
>
> presented to the server via standard Basic HTTP authentication (as
>   defined in RFC2617) as
>
> the username with an empty password.

How do I send the API key as the username and leave the PW empty? Here is what I have so far:

```
$subscriberInfo = [
    'email' => $email,
    'search' => $jobType,
    'location' => $location
];

$ch = curl_init('https://api.ExternalSiteHere');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $subscriberInfo);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
    ));

// execute!
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close the connection
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
die();
```

Comment: there is no possibility to send this via GET ? e.g. `https://api.ExternalSiteHere?api_key=123456abcdef`

Comment: No, not with this API call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, base64_encode("{$username}:{$password}"));`

In your case

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, base64_encode("{$username}:"));`

If that doesn't work drop the colon after username

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I just had to remove the `base64_encode`. So in the end, it looked like this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "username");`

Comment: Odd usually in basic authorization it requires base64_encode; glad it works anyhow